# Get only column names without execute sql query on plsql?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I got **ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined** error

I need to handle column names without run all long queries.
So i'm tring to collapse main query with

```
`select * from (--main query--) Where 1=2`
```

and handle emtpy result, success!

But there is a problem with some queries:

```
SELECT * => ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined
  FROM (SELECT A.*, A.ASSOCIATION_NO
          FROM CUSTOMER_INFO A
         WHERE A.ASSOCIATION_NO IS NOT NULL)
 WHERE 1 = 2
```

How can solve this ?

Comment: Give aliases to the duplicate columns? Your example is odd though... What are you actually trying to do with the 1=2 version, and how are you handling the empty results?

Comment: Maybe [using `dbms_sql` to parse and describe the query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47418383/266304) will do what you need? Just change `l_statement` in that answer to your inner query, and it will show all the column names.

Comment: [Possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47417675/266304).

Comment: first i need to insert columns with datatypes to database, second i dont want to run main query, just i need to get column names @AlexPoole

Comment: The linked answer only parses the query, it does not execute it - so you don't even need to add the 1=2 filter. (As long as it is just DML, not DDL...). It won't execute unless you tell it to. In the example I just display the column names, but you can get the data types from the `desc_tab` structure too, and insert that information somewhere instead of displaying it.

Comment: @AlexPoole how can i return col_type_name(VARCHAR2,DateTime etc.) in dbms_sql ? i can return col_type but i need col_type_name

Comment: You need to translate them, [as demo'd here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42564330/266304). The docs list the data types and their `col_type` values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pulling togetehr comments, you can use [`dbms_sql`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/arpls/DBMS_SQL.html) to parse (but not execute) the target query, and describe the result set columns to get the information you need.

[From those docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/arpls/DBMS_SQL.html#GUID-D1D54737-5201-4787-9BFA-B37BBA913BFA):

> Every SQL statement must be parsed by calling the `PARSE` procedures. Parsing the statement checks the statement's syntax and associates it with the cursor in your program.
>
> You can parse any DML or DDL statement. DDL statements are run on the parse, which performs the implied commit.

so aslong as the statement is just DML and not DDL it will *only* be parsed and not executed, since you don't carry on through the execution flow.

With a dummy table to demonstrate:

```
create table customer_info (association_no number(10),
  col_vc varchar2(20), col_d date, col_n number(2,5), col_ts timestamp(3));
```

then a basic version woudl be:

```
declare
  -- your target query, could be a pprocedure argument etc.
  l_statement varchar2(4000) := 'SELECT A.*, A.ASSOCIATION_NO
          FROM CUSTOMER_INFO A
         WHERE A.ASSOCIATION_NO IS NOT NULL';
  -- variabels dbms_sql use
  l_c pls_integer;
  l_col_cnt pls_integer;
  l_desc_t dbms_sql.desc_tab4;
  -- local variabels to hold columninfo as required
  l_column_name all_tab_cols.column_name%type;
  l_data_type varchar2(20);
begin
  l_c := dbms_sql.open_cursor;
  dbms_sql.parse(c=>l_c, statement=>l_statement, language_flag=>dbms_sql.native);
  dbms_sql.describe_columns3(c=>l_c, col_cnt=>l_col_cnt, desc_t=>l_desc_t);

  for i in 1..l_col_cnt loop
    l_column_name := l_desc_t(i).col_name;
    l_data_type := case l_desc_t(i).col_type
        when 1 then 'VARCHAR2'
        when 2 then 'NUMBER'
        when 12 then 'DATE'
        when 96 then 'CHAR'
        when 180 then 'TIMESTAMP'
        -- more types as needed
        ELSE 'unknown'
      end;
    case
      when l_desc_t(i).col_type in (1, 96) then -- or nchar etc. if needed
        l_data_type := l_data_type || '(' || l_desc_t(i).col_max_len || ')';
      when l_desc_t(i).col_type = 2 then
        l_data_type := l_data_type || '(' || l_desc_t(i).col_precision
          || ',' || l_desc_t(i).col_scale || ')';
      when l_desc_t(i).col_type = 180 then
        l_data_type := l_data_type || '(' || l_desc_t(i).col_scale || ')';
      else
        null;
    end case;

    -- use for insert, or just to debug for now
    dbms_output.put_line(l_column_name || ' ' || l_data_type);
  end loop;

  dbms_sql.close_cursor(l_c);
exception
  when others then
    if (dbms_sql.is_open(l_c)) then
      dbms_sql.close_cursor(l_c);
    end if;
    raise;
end;
/
```

which gives output:

```
ASSOCIATION_NO NUMBER(10,0)
COL_VC VARCHAR2(20)
COL_D DATE
COL_N NUMBER(2,5)
COL_TS TIMESTAMP(3)
ASSOCIATION_NO NUMBER(10,0)


PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

If you expect other data types then include suitable case handling for those too. The data types and equivalent numbers [are listed in the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Data-Types.html#GUID-7B72E154-677A-4342-A1EA-C74C1EA928E6).

Incidentally, I've linked to the 12c docs and tested against 12cR2, so I used the latest `desc_tab4` structure and `describe_columns3` function. Use the latest version of structure/call available for the version of Oracle you're developing against; if you're on 11gR2 then `desc_tab3`, for instance. The structure has a `col_type_name` but that doesn't seem to be populated, even in 12cR2. I don't have 18c to test against.

Answer (score 0):

Provide an alias name for the column as ASSOCIATION_NO is referred twice.

It would not be a problem if you are using single query.. but the query is written as subquery the issue is happening..

```
SELECT 
    A.*, A.ASSOCIATION_NO
FROM 
    CUSTOMER_INFO A
WHERE 
    A.ASSOCIATION_NO IS NOT NULL
```

This will work without any issue but as you are entering this as a subquery, system is throwing that error.

Comment: i cant modify --main query-- its dynamic and always worked well queries. I have to find a generic solution without fetching rows

Answer (score 0):

You can use [DBMS_SQL](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_sql.htm#i996963) to get the column names. You must first parse the query, then use one of the describe_columns procedures to get the information on the columns, which includes the names. This does not actually execute the query.

I'm not sure the parsing step will succeed, since as noted above, I think your query is technically invalid. You're lucky it currently runs.