# How can I get the column names returned by a query?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm looking for some way to generically determine what column names will be returned from a query. I've Googled around a bit, and all the answers I find are for determining the names of columns directly from a table. But I'm looking for a way to determine what columns will be returned from *any* query (without knowing what that query actually does).

For example, I'm looking for a way to do something like this:

`select COLUMN_NAME from (select...)`

...where that sub-select can be any query. But obviously that syntax doesn't work.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: You can create a temporary view `CREATE OR REPLACE xxx AS <inner-query>`, where<inner-query> might change , and use `user_view_columns` to derive column name(s).

Comment: You can [use dbms_sql](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47418383/266304), but it's a bit of a pain, and you need to be careful about SQL injection if you're going to use it for unknown/user-supplied queries (where they could pass a DDL statement instead, which would be execute by the parse).

Comment: What client programming environment are you using? dbms_sql can do it for PL/SQL, but other programming envs and drivers have their own methods for this, some kind of describe call.